# Add multiple TextView to a TableRow dynamically via sql loop

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, tablerow

I have searched and searched on here, but I cant seem to solve this problem. I have a `ScrollView`, inside the `ScrollView` is a `LinearLayout`, I want to read my SQL database and display the results like such;

```
Linear Layout
    ScrollView
        Linear Layout
            TableRow
               TextView
               TextView
            TableRow
               TextView
               TextView
        /Linear Layout
    /ScrollView
/LinearLayout
```

My code is as follows:

```
TableRow tRow;
            ContextThemeWrapper ttRow = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.coreTable);
            LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearCores);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);



            if (cores.moveToFirst()) {
                while (cores.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.e("CORE LIST", cores.getString(1));
                    tRow = new TableRow(ttRow);
                    tRow.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tRow.setOrientation(TableRow.VERTICAL);
                    tRow.setId(cores.getInt(0));
                    tRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_border);
                    ContextThemeWrapper newTxtA = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.coreHeaderView);
                    TextView tTextA = new TextView(newTxtA);
                    tTextA.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tTextA.setText(cores.getString(1) + " (Lvl " + cores.getString(2) + ")");
                    tRow.addView(tTextA);
                    TextView tTextB = new TextView(coreChooser.this);
                    tTextB.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    tTextB.setText(cores.getString(5));
                    tRow.addView(tTextB);
                    LL.addView(tRow);
                    cores.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

On my emulator it shows the first `tRow.addView`, but not the rest, however by background seems to stretch the past the screen.

I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) states the following:

> A `TableRow` should always be used as a child of a `TableLayout`. If a `TableRow`'s parent is not a `TableLayout`, the `TableRow` will behave as an horizontal `LinearLayout`.

If your intention is just to be able to make each pair of `TextView` share the common background `R.drawable.shape_border`, then use a nested `LinearLayout` in place of the `TableRow` (`TableRow` is extended from `LinearLayout` anyway).

Alternatively if there is some specific feature of `TableRow` you absolutely want to use, then make `R.id.linearCores` a `TableLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`.